# SpringBoot Native with GraalVM have expecting starting time but is really slow for heavy calculations

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

Hi I've done a PoC to test out SpringBoot v2.7.5 Native with GraalVM v22.3.0.

The purpose of the project was to run native SpringBoot on GCP AppEngine.

To test the performances I've implemented a basic Fibonacci sequence.

Going native makes heavy process taking twice time than normal ones.

Did somebody know why ?

Here is the results I had during my tests sessions :

Starting time:

| Starting time | AppEngine | Locally |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Native | 4 245ms | 8ms |
| Classic | 10 220ms | 2115ms |

Local tests:

*Quarkus Native tests was also made by using GraalVM*

| Fibonacci | SpringBoot | SpringBoot Native | Quarkus | Quarkus Native |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 000 000 | 77ms | 125ms | 103ms | 110ms |
| 5 000 000 | 204ms | 426ms | 363ms | 356ms |
| 10 000 000 | 327ms | 854ms | 435ms | 663ms |
| 30 000 000 | 894ms | 2 495ms | 1 523ms | 1 960ms |
| 90 000 000 | 3 571ms | 7 026ms | 4 464ms | 6 161ms |

If you want to check the code i'm using to make this test here it is :

https://github.com/tal0si/spring-boot-native-on-gcp-appengine

Comment: While native starts faster you loose some of the runtime optimizations that can be done, so eventually running a native app can have slower runtime performance (although will start faster). I also wonder what factor Google App Engine plays here.

Comment: Any news on this topic?